# AngularJs UI router strange naviation behavior on nested parameter view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some UI states defined as below:

```
//Parent State
$stateProvider.state(
    'customerdetail', {
    url: '/detail/:customerId',
    templateUrl: 'adminpages/customer.detail',
    controller: 'customerdetail',
    }
);

//Nested state1
$stateProvider.state(
    'customerdetail.detailInfo', {
        url: '/detailInfo',
        templateUrl: 'adminpages/customer.custDetail.detailInfo',
        controller: 'customerDetailInfo',
    }
);
//Nested state2
$stateProvider.state(
    'customerdetail.followRecord', {
        url: '/followRecord',
        templateUrl: 'adminpages/customer.custDetail.followRecord',
        controller: 'followRecord',
    }
);

//Some other state
$stateProvider.state(
    'newfollowrecords', {
        url: '/newfollowrecords',
        templateUrl: 'adminpages/customer.newfollowrecords',
        controller: 'newfollowrecord',
    }
);
```

When I click some url that change the nested state2 to some other state and then navigate back (use the browser history back), the browser flash very quickly to nested state2 and then finally stayed at nested state1.

Same operation has no such behavior on other nested states that does not has parameters.

So, I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the parameter I defined. Appreciate you can give some solution to me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I's my mistake that in the parent state controller, I programly switch to nested state1